# Rails Error - retuning scoped data

Tags: ruby-on-rails, scope

I am trying to make an app in Rails 4.

I have three models being:

```
User.rb (for authentication and fixed details)
Profile.rb (for user details which can change)
project.rb (for projects that users create)
```

The user model associations are:

```
has_many :project_questions, dependent: :destroy#, through: :projects
  accepts_nested_attributes_for :project_questions

  has_one :sweep
  accepts_nested_attributes_for :sweep

  has_one :educator_project_comment
  has_many :project_student_eois
  belongs_to :educator
  has_many :project_invitations
  has_one :video
  accepts_nested_attributes_for :video
  has_one :finalise, through: :sweep
  has_many :observations

  has_one :approval_request
  belongs_to :industry
  belongs_to :course

  has_and_belongs_to_many :users
  belongs_to :creator, class_name: 'User'
  has_many :profiles, through: :industry
```

The profile model associations are:

```
has_one :setting
  has_one :phone#, :through => :setting
  has_one :address#, :through => :setting
  belongs_to :university
  belongs_to :organisation
  belongs_to :user
  has_many :notices
  belongs_to :faculty
  belongs_to :industry
  has_one :video
  has_many :feedbacks
```

The user model associations are:

```
has_one :account_history
  has_one :active_user_policy
  has_one :profile
  has_one :shortlist
  has_one :match_maker
  has_many :authentications
  has_many :relationships, foreign_key: "follower_id", dependent: :destroy
  has_many :followed_users, through: :relationships, source: :followed
  has_many :followers, through: :reverse_relationships
  has_and_belongs_to_many :projects
  has_and_belongs_to_many :programs
  has_and_belongs_to_many :proposals
  has_one :policy_privacy
  has_one :policy_user
  has_many :project_questions
  has_many :project_answers
  has_one :signature_block
  has_one :video
  has_many :project_invitations
  has_many :feedbacks
  accepts_nested_attributes_for :feedbacks
  has_many :reviewers, :through => :feedbacks, :class_name => 'User'
  has_many :created_feedbacks, :class_name => 'Feedback', :foreign_key => 'reviewer_id'
  has_many :reviewed_users, :through => :feedbacks_left, :source => :user, :class_name => 'User'
  has_one :signature_block
```

In my projects_controller, I have:

```
def show

    @project = Project.find(params[:id])
    @creator = User.find(@project.creator_id)
    @creator_profile = @creator.profile

  end
```

The association between user and project is that project belongs to user. In my project table, I have an integer attribute called 'creator_id'. I don't have a separate 'user_id' field.

I have creator, because I want to define users who create projects (so that the project creator links to that user's profile (as opposed to the profile of the current_user who is looking at the project).

I have defined three scopes in project.rb as:

```
scope :creator, lambda { where(@creator_profile = user.profile_id)}

  scope :current, lambda { where('project.start_date >= ?', Date.today)}
  scope :visible, lambda { joins(:sweep => :disclosure).where('disclosures.allusers' => 'true')
    .joins(:sweep => :finalise).where('finalises.draft' => 'false') }
```

The method 'all_current_for_creator' is defined in my project.rb as:

```
def self.all_current_for_creator(creator)
    if creator.profile.present?
       creator.current.visible
    else
      guest_visible
    end
  end
```

In my profile show page, I render a partial, to show the creators current projects as:

```
<div class="categorytitle">
      Current Collaborative Projects
    </div>

    <div class="categorybody">

    <div class="row">
      <div class="col-md-10 col-md-offset-1">
      <% if Project.all_current_for_creator(@creator).!blank? %>

        <% Project.all_current_for_creator(@creator).sort_by(&:created_at).each do |project| %>
         <div class="row"> <div class="projectprofilerow">
            <div class="col-md-4">
              <div class="projectindex">
                <%= image_tag project.hero_image_url, width: '70', height: '70' if project.hero_image.present? %>
              </div>
            </div>
            <div class="col-md-8">
              <div class="row">
                <div class="col-md-12">
                  <div class="indexheading"> <%= link_to project.title, project %> </div>
                </div>
              </div>
              <div class="row">
                <div class="col-md-12">
                  <div class="indexsubtext">    
                    <%= truncate(project.description, :ommission => "...", :length => 250) %>
                  </div> </div>              
                </div>
              </div>
            </div>
      </div>
      <% end %>
        <% else %>
          <%= render :text => "No current projects".html_safe %>     

    <% end %>
  </div>
</div>


    </div>
```

I have also tried '.any?' instead of !blank.  When i try checking for blank, I get this error:

```
wrong number of arguments (1 for 0)
```

When I try .any?, I get this error:

```
undefined method `any?' for nil:NilClass
```

I think the reason for this is that nil isn't a thing so any can't test on it, but I get an error when I try .present? so I'm not clear on that.

```
    Can anyone see where I'm going wrong?
```

Comment: `creator` should be defined as a `belongs_to` association on `Project`. The scope you are using in its place is almost certainly not what you want.

Comment: Hi - i have projects belonging to users. My project table has an integer field for creator_id (which is a user)

Comment: You can use `belongs_to` for both. Add `belongs_to :creator, class_name: 'User'` to `Project` and you can access the creator by `project.creator`.

Comment: Hi, i tried that. It gives me the same error: wrong number of arguments (1 for 0). When I then tried changing @creator to @project.creator, it says 
undefined method `creator' for nil:NilClass. I don't think this approach works with the rest of my setup

Comment: Im wondering if that's because my project model has got 'has and belongs to many' relationship with user?

Comment: I think your problems are stemming from how your relationships are defined. If you post your models, I can make some suggestions.